# Using pypdfocr library from within a Python script

Tags: python, pdf, ocr

How can you run pypdfocr from within a Python script, as opposed to the command line?

This question [How to call pypdfocr functions to use them in a python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39988381/how-to-call-pypdfocr-functions-to-use-them-in-a-python-script) approaches the answer I want, but doesn't quite get there.

```
import pypdfocr
from pypdfocr import pypdfocr
from pypdfocr.pypdfocr import PyPDFOCR as pocr

filepath = 'C:/myfolder/myPDF.pdf'

newfile = pocr.run_conversion(filepath)
```

This throws an error:

```
Unbound method  run_conversion must be called with PyPDFOCR instance as first argument.
```

Can someone help me fill in the (likely obvious) missing piece?

Comment: Why do you have `from pypdfocr import pypdfocr` in your first line? Shouldn't it be `import pypdfocr`?

Comment: Yes, thank you, fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to run run_conversion without an object.

`run_conversion` is a method of the class `PyPDFOCR`. So you will need an object of that class to run the method.

Once you have made an `PyPDFOCR` object (for instance `my_ocr`), you should be able to write:

```
newfile = my_ocr.run_conversion(filepath)
```

Comment: "Once you have made an PyPDFOCR object..." -- how does one do that?

Comment: `my_ocr =pocr()`  in this example?

Comment: Yes, `my_ocr = pocr()` should be enough. Unfortunately, run_conversion fails because the object has not been properly initialised yet. Apparently you'll have to use `my_ocr.go(...)` instead of `my_ocr.run_conversion()`. I'm not sure which options have to be used. If I try `my_ocr.go([filepath])`, the program seems to go into some endless loop ...

Answer (score 0):

I made a system call with success.

```
cmd = "pypdfocr '"+str(file)+"'"
os.system(cmd)
```